# G+ doesn't accept my og:image

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I can't seem to figure out why G+ doesn't show the photo on my page http://cruiser.mototribe.com/photo/march-contest

It has the proper meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cruiser.mototribe.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/photos/new/bikeer%2520pose.jpg" />
```

The testing tool confirms the og:image tags
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://cruiser.mototribe.com/photo/march-contest

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ Google has informed that:

> Images that are too small or not square enough are not included in the
>   +Snippet, even if the images are explicitly referenced by schema.org microdata or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at
>   least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect
>   ratio must be no greater than 3.0.

I think your image has adequate height and width but the aspect ratio should be taken care of.

One more info: I did not see the image in my webmastertool account.

Comment: it doesn't even work on a square image: http://cruiser.mototribe.com/photo/tgif-friends Not sure what you mean with webmastertool account?

Comment: thanks. When I check the urls it does show type:image http://cruiser.mototribe.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/photos/new/bikeer%2520pose.jpg